# Uncontrolled input of elements with dynamic (api fetched) names?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, formik

I am fetching list of checkboxes from API which in typescript looks like that:

```
product: { list: { [key: string]: boolean } }
```

So, while using Formik, my fiend name varies and are dynamically created. Some examples:

```
product.list.users
product.list.parts
product.list.utils
```

However, since Formik's Form initial values cannot be fetched before the API request happens (UX), I really don't have initial values for these checkboxes (users, parts, utils). Therefore I am getting an error about transitioning from uncontrolled input to controlled ones.

Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Add default values for your checkboxes.

Comment: Hmmm not working, both defaultChecked={false} and value={0} (its input type so no boolean value).

Comment: Ok got it, you were right. The formik should accept defaultChecked as a proper value if its input type=checkbox